# How to compress a folder in yii2 web app into a zip?

Tags: php, yii2, zip

I am trying to zip a folder.

This is the function in `ExportarController.php`

```
public function zipping(){
        $rootPath = realpath('results/');

        // Initialize archive object
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open('../web/descargas/Region.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        // Initialize empty "delete list"
        $filesToDelete = array();

        // Create recursive directory iterator
        /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file)
        {
            // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
            if (!$file->isDir())
            {
                // Get real and relative path for current file
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

                // Add current file to archive
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

                // Add current file to "delete list"
                // delete it later cause ZipArchive create archive only after calling close function and ZipArchive lock files until archive created)
                if ($file->getFilename() != 'important.txt')
                {
                    $filesToDelete[] = $filePath;
                }
            }
        }

        // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
        $zip->close();

        // Delete all files from "delete list"
        foreach ($filesToDelete as $file)
        {
            unlink($file);
        }

    }
```

It worked pefectly when I tried it outside `yii2` webapp. But when I added the function to `yii2` controller I got the error:

```
Class 'app\controllers\ZipArchive' not found
```

Do you know what is going wrong? does it have something to do with the directory I'm trying to write in?

Please help me.

Thank you so much.

**SOLUTION**

It was cuz of the namespace, I had to ad \ to every ziparchive function.

Like \ZipArchive()  and \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: may be your ZipArchive Class namespace is missing from the Controller file

Comment: @ck_arjun and Maurocrispin. Will this download the .zip files or it will just create it. I have a situation where i want to fetch files from folder and make zip and then download it.. Please reply..

Comment: This function is just creating zip file. I have separate function to download the zip file. @SalmanRiyaz

Answer (score 2):

### First enable php zip extension

$zip = new \ZipArchive();

```
                $test = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), rand(0, 999999999) . '.zip');
                var_dump($test);
                $res = $zip->open($test, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

                if ($res) {
                    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {

                        $zip->addFile($data['file_name'],'chat_'. $data['chatID'] .'.csv');

                    }
                    $zip->close();
                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=chat_' . date('Ymd_His'). '.zip');
                    readfile($test);

                } else {
                    echo 'zip error';
                    die;
                }
```

---

Read for More : http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php